# SQL Group Multiple Columns and count

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a productivity table with the following fields

```
EmpName Client    Sclient   BillGrp WkdDate
KK      Parallon  Atlanta   IP      12-Jul-16
KK      Kiwitek   Ozark     OP      11-Jul-16
JJ     Parallon   Atlanta   OP      10-Jul-16
JJ     Kiwitek    Ozark     IP      11-Jul-16
```

I need something like this

```
EmpName Client   BillGrp  Count
KK      Parallon IP       2
JJ      Parallon OP       2
```

In short There has to be only one entry for each EmpName and the Client and BillGrp with maximum entries for that EmpName are to be returned with the overall counts in Count Field

Comment: `select EmpName, Client, BillGrp, Count(1) from.. Group by EmpName, Client, BillGrp`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks buddy.. it worked

Answer (score 1):

You state this is the working query, but do you see any issue with the where clause? You are redundantly repeating a join predicate, and the second predicate could also be regarded part of the join too.

What is the point of asking for MAX(EmpName) if you include EmpName in the group by clause?

```
SELECT
        MAX(EmpName)
      , MAX(P.Client)
      , MAX(P.BillGrp)
      , Target
      , COUNT(*)
FROM Productivity P
        LEFT JOIN Targets T ON P.Client = T.Client
WHERE P.Client = T.Client
AND P.BillGrp = T.BillGrp
GROUP BY
        P.EmpName
      , T.Target
```

the non-aggregating columns of the select clause should be listed in the group by clause (and vice-versa) i.e:

```
SELECT
        T.Target
      , MAX(EmpName)
      , MAX(P.Client)
      , MAX(P.BillGrp)
      , COUNT(*)
FROM Productivity P
        LEFT JOIN Targets T ON P.Client = T.Client
                           AND P.BillGrp = T.BillGrp
GROUP BY
        T.Target
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpName, Client, BillGrp, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM table 
GROUP BY EmpName
```

Comment: Yep.. It worked like a charm.. Fortunately I got it to work before I could see your answer.. But thanks anyways.. And Here is my version of the query.. Select max(EmpName), max(P.Client) , max(P.BillGrp), Target, Count(*)  from Productivity P left Join Targets T on P.Client = T.Client

Where P.Client = T.Client and P.BillGrp = T.BillGrp Group By P.EmpName,T.Target.. I've mapped the targets from a different file..

Comment: Used_By_Akready If i dont use group by on empname and other fields.. it throws me an error..!!!